# Haskell - Which parameters in this function?

Tags: haskell, arguments

can someone tell me the two parameters applied to map in this function, or add parenthesis to this please ?

```
pad n ys = map Just ys ++ replicate k Nothing
    where k = n - (length ys `mod` n)
```

Thanks !

Comment: function call is the highest precedence operator hence...

Comment: `map` is applied to `Just` and `ys`

Comment: It's `(map Just ys) ++ (replicate k Nothing)`.

Answer (score 2):

Function application binds quite tightly:

```
map Just ys ++ replicate k Nothing
```

parses as:

```
(map Just ys) ++ (replicate k Nothing)
```

That is, the function is the constructor `Just` and the container/list is `ys`.

Comment: I feel compelled to add: ++ is an operator and takes arguments just like a function, too, but - as infix operator - with very low precedence.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can figure it out by considering the type:

```
Prelude> pad n ys = map Just ys ++ replicate n Nothing
Prelude> :t pad
pad :: Int -> [a] -> [Maybe a]

Prelude> pad n ys = map Just (ys ++ replicate n Nothing)
Prelude> :t pad
pad :: Int -> [Maybe a] -> [Maybe (Maybe a)]

Prelude> pad n ys = (map Just ys) ++ (replicate n Nothing)
Prelude> :t pad
pad :: Int -> [a] -> [Maybe a]
```